# What does "Sunny Greetings" mean when starting a conversation?

Tags: conversation

Recently I met a new friend who uses the message "Sunny Greetings" every time we start a conversation, especially via message.

What makes this word "Sunny" becomes appropriate?

Will it depend on any weather of the day?

Can I use this word after like let's say 3 PM of the day?

Comment: Alexander, that isn't idiomatic in British, US American, Australian, South African or Zimbabwean English, anyway.

What did your dictionary say *sunny* meant, please?

When you ask about the weather and the time of day, did you notice how they would compare to using phrases like *Good day/ morning/ afternoon/ evening/ night*?

None of those means anything like *I see we're having good (as in weather)* nor *I see at this (3pm) time of day, things look good.*

All mean *I wish you/ hope you have a good (noun)*

D'you see why that can't be perfectly translated to *sunny*, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your new friend German?

The term "sunny greetings" is used in German (Mit sonnigen Grüßen). See: http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/sunny+greetings.html

My knowledge of German is insufficient to research the term properly, I'm sorry.

I have seen the term used in English on postcards and the like. (For example, "Sunny greetings from Bristol.") I am unaware of it being used generally as a greeting in English, but I could well be wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not used as a general greeting in the UK.

Comment: No, Kate. In 60 years of listening, I've never once noticed that, nor anything close to it.

Comment: I have read that "sunny" is a popular word in Japan, though I don't know if "sunny greeting" is an idiom there or not.

Comment: I had an old law professor who offered "fraternal greetings" to all and sundry who crossed his path.

Comment: My Danish friend used that for starting a written message and I think it showed the mood from her side both physically and mentally; however, now it's rainy here. I'm writing an email to a friend and I'm pretty sure that I won't put 'rainy greetings' to start the writing.